# dplyr concatenate column by variable value

Tags: r, dplyr, concatenation, summarize

I can concatenate one column of `data.frame`, following the code as below if the column name is available.

- However, How about the "column" name saved in the variable?
- Further question is, how can I specify the columns by the value of a variable? (`!!sym()` ?)

Here are test code:

```
> library(dplyr)
> packageVersion("dplyr")
[1] ‘1.0.7’

> df <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = c("A", "B", "A"))
> df %>%
  group_by(y) %>%
  summarise(z = paste(x, collapse = ","))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  y     z    
  <chr> <chr>
1 A     1,3  
2 B     2
```

I have a variable `a`, with the value `x`, How can I do above summarize?

```
> a <- "x"
> df %>%
  group_by(y) %>%
  summarise(z = paste(a, collapse = ","))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  y     z    
  <chr> <chr>
1 A     x    
2 B     x
```

#### Solution-1: use `!!sym()`

```
> a <- "x"
> df %>%
  group_by(y) %>%
  summarise(z = paste(!!sym(a), collapse = ","))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  y     z    
  <chr> <chr>
1 A     1,3  
2 B     2
```

#### Solution-2: Assign the column to new variable

```
> df %>%
  group_by(y) %>%
  rename(new_col = a) %>%
  summarise(z = paste(new_col, collapse = ","))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
  y     z    
  <chr> <chr>
1 A     1,3  
2 B     2
```

Are there any other ways to do the job?

similar questions could be found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15935166/2530783 ,https://stackoverflow.com/a/50537209/2530783,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some other options -

1. Use `.data` -

```
library(dplyr)

a <- "x"
df %>% group_by(y) %>% summarise(z = toString(.data[[a]]))

#   y     z    
#  <chr> <chr>
#1 A     1, 3 
#2 B     2
```

2. `get`

```
df %>% group_by(y) %>% summarise(z = toString(get(a)))
```

3. `as.name`

```
df %>% group_by(y) %>% summarise(z = toString(!!as.name(a)))
```

`paste(..., collapse = ',')` is equivalent to `toString`.